# How do I intentionally detach HEAD in git?

Tags: git, git-checkout

If I do `git checkout HEAD^`, I get this:

```
$ git checkout HEAD^
Note: checking out 'HEAD^'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at...
$
```

Veteran git users are probably very familiar with this. But if I do `git checkout HEAD`, nothing happens:

```
$ git checkout HEAD
$
```

I'd like to create the "detached HEAD" state for the commit at the head of my current branch. How do I do that?

Comment: @Mat: pretty much what the explanatory message says. I want to make some experimental commits or rebasing or amending, but I don't need to retain my changes. So I'm trying to create a throwaway copy of a branch.

Comment: Why don't you just create a branch, and delete it when you're done? Same effect.

Comment: Since git1.7.5, `git checkout --detach` should work as well. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19495843/6309).

Comment: It's useful when you want to delete the branch you're currently on.

Comment: "How to intentionally detach a head" would have been a formidable title…

Comment: Detaching is one way to ensure a fetch works, to avoid the dreaded:  `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`

Comment: Very useful for merging changes from one machine to another, when they're on remote tracking branches but only one machine can see the other (eg laptop/server).  Run `git checkout --detach` on server, then `git push server` on laptop, then `git checkout master` on server to see changes made on laptop.

Comment: I was in the wrong branch, edited files and couldn't switch to the right branch because of conflicts. I successfully used `git checkout --detach` to create a dangling commit without polluting my `master` branch. Once in the feature branch I `cherry-pick`ed the commit by revision number.

Comment: Useful when you have multiple working trees and want both of them to be on the same branch, which is not possible. You can however enter detached head state in one of the working tree, which means you will be able to checkout the branch you want in the other work tree.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since git 1.7.5 (April 2011), you can use the `git checkout --detach` command.
([Since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), you would use `git switch --detach`)

See [commit 326696](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32669671c7746888aa1e3832907deb7fc8405061)

### `checkout`: introduce `--detach` synonym for "`git checkout foo^{commit}`"

> For example, one might use this when making a temporary merge to test that two topics work well together.

---

[Commit 8ced1aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ced1aa08f9e1798b2b3fec41a0598ef79b477fe) (git 1.7.11.3, July 2012) disallows `--detach` on unborn branch, so this won't fail on a null `HEAD`:

```
git checkout --orphan foo
git checkout --detach
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

---

Only the upcoming git 1.8.4.2 or 1.8.5 (Q4 2013) clarifies the syntax.
See [commit 26776c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26776c9737a6b5b0e7aab142aef6ba856d8b46ca):

> Separate this case into two syntactical forms, mimicking the way how the DESCRIPTION section shows this usage.
> Also update the text that explains the syntax to name the commit to detach `HEAD` at to clarify.

```
'git checkout' [--detach] <commit>::
```

> Prepare to work on top of `<commit>`, by detaching `HEAD` at it ([see "DETACHED HEAD" section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)), and updating the index and the tree will be the state recorded in the commit plus the local modifications.
>
> 1. When the `<commit>` argument is a branch name, the `--detach` option can be used to detach `HEAD` at the tip of the branch (`git checkout <branch>` would check out that branch without detaching `HEAD`).
> 2. **Omitting `<branch>` detaches `HEAD` at the tip of the current branch**.

That last point is precisely what you want to do for your current branch:

```
git checkout --detach
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is definitely nicer than the `master^0` method.

Comment: In a newly-initialized repo, `git checkout --detach` fails with the error message `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: @ChrisMartin Yes, that is expected. You need to make at least one commit first.

Comment: It's impossible to enter a detached head state without making a commit?

Comment: @ChrisMartin detached head means a direct checkout of a commit. If you don't have *any* commit, ... no detached head possible.

Answer (score 11):

This command creates a detached head state from any given branch name (in this case, master):

```
git checkout master^0
```

Checking out commit hashes also automatically creates a detached head state, no need for `^0`:

```
git checkout 823112f444cb4aa70032feea6e8e5eb79d0e1ed0
```

And of course the shorter hashes as well:

```
git checkout 823112f
```

Comment: Not sure you even need the `^0` bit when you're checking out by SHA, but I haven't tested that...

Comment: It's still useful to know that it works with commit hashes and tag names.  That makes it easy to use in git-related scripts without worrying about whether you're dealing with a tag name, a commit hash or a branch name.